# Define what return will be depending on param passed

Tags: typescript

I know all the possible values a param of a function can be. And if the param is a certain key, I know what the value will be. I am typing up the `redis.get` function for those of you that are familiar with redis. It's a key-value store.

```
type IA = 'a'
type IAData = string;

type IB = 'b'
type IBData = number;

type IRedisGet =
  | ((key: IA) => IAData)
  | ((key: IB) => IBData)

export const redistGet: IRedisGet = (key) => {
  if (key === 'a') {
    return 'a';
  } else if (key === 'b') {
    return 12;
  } else {
    throw new Error('invalid key');
  }
}
```

However this gives me the error:

```
Type '(key: any) => "a" | 12' is not assignable to type 'IRedisGet'.
  Type '(key: any) => "a" | 12' is not assignable to type '(key: "a") => string'.
    Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322
```

Does anyone know how to do this in Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) are typically how to handle this.

```
function redisGet(key: IA): IAData
function redisGet(key: IB): IBData
function redisGet(key: IA | IB): IAData | IBData {
  //...
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgglAvFA5AQxQKFJWcAiawaSUAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcm240MAQqSgEZY7sOhYqVoBXALY8IlZq1wwAShAAm1MgHEIwJJihQAPlAAUxgNYQQALjwBKJAD48wtLb2GT5yzc73ETzhc3TAAzMVoAY2BqAHtaKEpVdS1gL2s7HwIiNFDwqNj4xLVNbTSfDltyl1zI6LiEpJLUi3T4D19Ml3ahbKgAb3dqEJMWpERkdBR7Af19ROAxSnjJ5n0AXygIABsyaCGRyzGJvmn3Oe1F+IBGACZVqA3t3f6zqGAAC0oYgHcoWghfgBRShfSjGFB0ABuaC21BUUBaU3ua0wayAA)

Comment: Thanks this is awesome. Is there anyway to do this in a function defined inside of an object? So like inline function way to define this?